# What's the best way to get all content for a field?

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes

Given an array of field IDs, I want to get all content for those fields.
So, in this situation:

- entry 1

  - field ID 1: 'test'
- entry 2

  - field ID 1: 'test test'

I want to end up with `array('test', 'test test')`.
I now iterate through all content from the content table to check the field's handle against the handle of the field I'm looking for, but there must be a better way.

See [this service](https://github.com/nilsenpaul/nptypeahead/blob/master/nptypeahead/services/NpTypeAhead_DataService.php) to see what code I use now.

Comment: Hey Paul - can you post the code you are using to iterate through all the content? Are you running a SQL query?

Comment: I did. I posted a link to the service on Github.

Comment: I've been messing around throughout the day with fancy nested SQL queries to try and simplify your service algorithm, but couldn't get anything to work...yet!